# Convert DateOffset to local datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to display the Datetimeoffset field as date time in my view. Currently when i apply displayformat it doesnt do anything. I am looking for DD/MM/yyyy and seconds format

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

My view currently shows     /Date(1490029476910)/

How do I handle the formatting and display the local time using the viewmodel

Comment: You're currently displaying a JSON date. You'll only get that from JSON, as the name implies, which means you're handling this via AJAX. To avoid this, look into a different JSON serializer like NewtonSoft.Json, which will let you control the formatting of date serialization in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

use `ApplyFormatInEditMode=true` property to your attribute,

true if the formatting string applies to the field value in edit mode; default value is false

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

Comment: I applied this to my view model but it didnt make any difference [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]

Answer (score 0):

You can use data annotation called [DataType(DataType.Date)] and ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString ="{0:d}"

Eg :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString ="{0:d}")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "DataDate cannot be empty")]
        public DateTime? DataDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Mine is DateOffSet field not DateTime